# Remove black default clothes in MB-Lab

Tags: modifiers, armature

How is going?

I'm playing with the latest version of MB-Lab [addon](https://mb-lab-community.github.io/MB-Lab.github.io/) creating a model. But at the rendering time, I can not remove the default black underwear, so appears the whole time there.

(Here is an example of a character with the underwear in place.[image: default character showing black underwear]

Does someone know how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why this question was closed for lacking clarity, as it is clear enough to be able to answer. Hopefully my edit will get it reopened.  Meanwhile, here's one answer:   Select the character and go into the material properties panel.  Find the material MBLab_generic.  Use the drop down menu to switch it to MBLab_skin2.

Comment: Thank you—this answer is better than the one poster below—consider writing it as an Answer, please.

Answer (score 3):

If you go into the shader tab, you'll see a material called MBlab_generic and then whatever the asset name is.

Go into *Edit Mode* and click the *Select* button with that shader highlighted, it should select all the faces that have that black shader. Select your skin shader and click *Assign*, it should then assign that shader to the black sections.